# how to use bootstrap alert message inside a javascript function?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-modal

I would like to add Bootstrap alert messages inside the JavaScript function.

Eg:

```
<div class="alert alert-success fade in">
     <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
     <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent successfully.
</div>
```

The above div content displays a success message. I want to call this inside my JavaScript code, if my web service returns a success message.

Answer (score 4):

Create a `class` to initially hide the `alert`

```
.hide{
  display:none
}

<div id = "alertId" class="alert alert-success fade in hide">
       //rest of code
</div>
```

In js in the success function

```
 document.getElementById('alertId').classList.remove('hide')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set toggle your web service returns. This example working with click function.

```js
function toggleAlert(){
    $(".alert").toggleClass('in out'); 
    return false; // Keep close.bs.alert event from removing from DOM
}


$("#btn").on("click", toggleAlert);
$('#bsalert').on('close.bs.alert', toggleAlert)
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">Toggle</button>

<div class="alert alert-info fade out" id="bsalert">
  <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
  <strong>Info!</strong> This alert box could indicate a neutral informative or action
</div>

<div>
    content
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$("#success-alert").hide();
$("#test").click(function showAlert() {
    $("#success-alert").fadeTo(2000, 500).slideUp(500, function(){
   $("#success-alert").slideUp(500);
    });   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div>
    <button id="test">Result</button>
</div>

<div class="alert alert-success" id="success-alert">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been sent successfully.
</div>
```

You can use the above snippet code, but place the code in button `.click()` event after the return of the server result.